# Set the value of a td using jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

From the check box which is in each row, if it is checked I want to update the table data value for that row. I tried with:

```
$('#'+id).each(function(index, cell){
        $('#data2').html("New Value");
    });
```

But it is not working. I access the ID by:

```
            if ($('.cbox1:checked').length) {
                      var id = '';
                      $('.cbox1:checked').each(function () {
                        id = $(this).val();
                      });
              }
```

My Html is

```
        <table class="mytable" id="tableid" > 
        <tr> 
            <th style="width: 10px;"> </th> 
            <th> DATA1</th> 
            <th>DATA2</th> 
            <th>DATA3 </th> 
        </tr> 
        <tr contenteditable="false" class="content193" id="193"> 
            <td>  <input class="cbox1" type="checkbox" value="193"></td> 
            <td id="data1">45</td> 
            <td id="data2">566</td> 
            <td id="data3"> 12.12.2016</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr contenteditable="false" class="content194" id="194"> 
            <td><input class="cbox1" type="checkbox" value="194"></td> 
            <td id="data1">456</td> 
            <td id="data2">6745</td> 
            <td id="data3"> 11.10.2016</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr contenteditable="false" class="content199" id="199"> 
            <td><input class="cbox1" type="checkbox" value="199"></td> 
            <td id="data1">tr</td> 
            <td id="data2">24</td> 
            <td id="data3"> 20.01.2015</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr contenteditable="false" class="content201" id="201"> 
            <td><input class="cbox1" type="checkbox" value="201"></td> 
            <td id="data1">tr</td> 
            <td id="data2">24</td> 
            <td id="data3"> 20.01.2015</td> 
        </tr> 
    </table>
```

Comment: `$('#'+id).each...` there should only be one `'#' + id` of anything per document

Comment: @danronmoon : i didnt get it.please make it clearer

Comment: Multiples of the same id attribute are invalid HTML. You will need to change the repeated id's to use classes instead.

Comment: @winterblood : actually these table are generated from database using PHP

Comment: Then your PHP is generating invalid HTML. There are no guarantees of anything working properly if you are using invalid HTML like this.

Comment: But iam making use of class in each row updated like this : **<tr contenteditable="false" class="content<?php echo $record->ID;?>" id="<?php echo $record->ID;?>">**

Comment: @mastermind You have multiple `id="data1"`, that's the problem.

Comment: Also, even if multiple IDs were allowed, your jQuery code isn't looking for the ID in a specific row.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You have two or more elements with the same id. This is invalid HTML, and id selectors will not work properly while you have this.

Comment: But is nt it possible to distinguish the row by the Unique ID of class ?

Comment: Id is the one that has to be unique. Any amount of elements can have the same class.

Comment: So, what step shall i take to make this simpler and efficient

Comment: change them all to class and use traverses `$('.cbox1').change(function() var $row = $(this).closest('tr') })` then from $row ..`$row.find('td').eq(2).text('new value'); })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use classes instead of IDs for the elements that are repeated on each row. Then make the selector look for the class in the selected row.

```js
$("#doit").click(function() {
  $('.cbox1:checked').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $('#' + id + ' .data2').html("New Value");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mytable" id="tableid">
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 10px;"></th>
    <th>DATA1</th>
    <th>DATA2</th>
    <th>DATA3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr contenteditable="false" class="content193" id="193">
    <td>
      <input class="cbox1" type="checkbox" value="193">
    </td>
    <td class="data1">45</td>
    <td class="data2">566</td>
    <td class="data3">12.12.2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr contenteditable="false" class="content194" id="194">
    <td>
      <input class="cbox1" type="checkbox" value="194">
    </td>
    <td class="data1">456</td>
    <td class="data2">6745</td>
    <td class="data3">11.10.2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr contenteditable="false" class="content199" id="199">
    <td>
      <input class="cbox1" type="checkbox" value="199">
    </td>
    <td class="data1">tr</td>
    <td class="data2">24</td>
    <td class="data3">20.01.2015</td>
  </tr>
  <tr contenteditable="false" class="content201" id="201">
    <td>
      <input class="cbox1" type="checkbox" value="201">
    </td>
    <td class="data1">tr</td>
    <td class="data2">24</td>
    <td class="data3">20.01.2015</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="doit">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need the classes or ids at all. You can just find the row closest to the changed element and just access it's `td`s directly:

```js
$('.cbox1').change(function(){
  
  var $row = $(this).closest('tr'); //get the current row
  
  $row.find('td').eq(1).text('new value'); // change first cell
  $row.find('td').eq(2).text('new value'); // change second cell
  $row.find('td').eq(3).text('new value'); // change third cell
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mytable" id="tableid" > 
        <tr> 
            <th style="width: 10px;"> </th> 
            <th> DATA1</th> 
            <th>DATA2</th> 
            <th>DATA3 </th> 
        </tr> 
        <tr contenteditable="false" class="content193" id="193"> 
            <td>  <input class="cbox1" type="checkbox" value="193"></td> 
            <td>45</td> 
            <td>566</td> 
            <td> 12.12.2016</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr contenteditable="false" class="content194" id="194"> 
            <td><input class="cbox1" type="checkbox" value="194"></td> 
            <td>456</td> 
            <td>6745</td> 
            <td> 11.10.2016</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr contenteditable="false" class="content199" id="199"> 
            <td><input class="cbox1" type="checkbox" value="199"></td> 
            <td>19</td> 
            <td>24</td> 
            <td> 20.01.2015</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr contenteditable="false" class="content201" id="201"> 
            <td><input class="cbox1" type="checkbox" value="201"></td> 
            <td>15</td> 
            <td>24</td> 
            <td> 20.01.2015</td> 
        </tr> 
    </table>
```