# VBScript to add and delete row dynamcially

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, vbscript

I would like to add a new row to my HTML table and delete the row dynamically using VBScript. Iam new to this can anyone guide me how to do this.

Comment: [Your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891889/set-the-value-of-a-td-using-jquery) is good, because it is clear and shows prior and research. This however is too brief and too broad, and may close. If you can write your questions like the other one, they will be a better fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this will be Internet Explorer specific. Might not work on other browsers/

```
 Sub AddRow() 
         Dim objTable : Set objTable = window.document.getElementById("tableid") 
         Dim objRow : Set objRow = objTable.insertRow() 
         Dim intCount, objCell 
         For intCount = 0 To 2 
             Set objCell = objRow.insertCell() 
             objCell.innerHTML = "Content for cell") 
         Next 
     End Sub
```

For delete use

```
window.document.getElementById("tableid").deleteRow(oRow.rowIndex);
```